# Google Realtime API / Drive - Cursor gets stolen if user is in different input field

Tags: google-api, google-drive-realtime-api

When I use the realtime API, I noticed that on collaborative strings, if User B begins typing and User A is in an input field elsewhere on the page, User A's cursor gets stolen and placed into the collaborative string field.

Is there a way to prevent this? Why does it occur in the first place?

Comment: The realtime API doesn't do anything with users cursors, so this must be something your app is doing.  If you post relevant code snippets, someone may be able to help.

Comment: Commenting out the below from rtpg.string.js fixed this issue

//$(rtpg.string.INPUT_SELECTOR).get(0).setSelectionRange(evt.newIndex, $(rtpg.string.INPUT_SELECTOR).get(0).selectionEnd);

Comment: So, this prevents User A from losing her cursor to User B when User B is active in the realtime string (if User A is in a different text field).

Comment: HOWEVER, if User A is also in the collaborative notes section, and she is typing in Position 1 (way up on the the top of the note), and User B begins typing in Position 2...the way things are now...User A has her cursor moved to where User B is typing, and they begin colliding. Is there anyway to solve for this?